# Getting sound for notification on emulator, but notification isn't displaying(It does on physical device) (Android

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-firebase, react-native-push-notification

Notifications aren't showing on emulator but are on a physical device. I still get the sound for the device.

```
    useEffect(() => {
      PushNotification.createChannel(
        {
          channelId: "fcm_fallback_notification_channel", // (required)
          channelName: "My channel", // (required)
          channelDescription: "A channel to categorise your notifications", // (optional) default: undefined.
          playSound: false, // (optional) default: true
          soundName: "default", // (optional) See `soundName` parameter of `localNotification` function
          importance: Importance.HIGH, // (optional) default: Importance.HIGH. Int value of the Android notification importance
          vibrate: true, // (optional) default: true. Creates the default vibration patten if true.
        },
        (created) => console.log(`createChannel returned '${created}'`) // (optional) callback returns whether the channel was created, false means it already existed.
      );

      PushNotification.channelExists('fcm_fallback_notification_channel', function (exists) {
        console.log(exists); // true/false
      });

      PushNotification.getChannels(function (channel_ids) {
        console.log(channel_ids); // ['channel_id_1']
      });
      const unsubscribe = messaging().onMessage(async (remoteMessage) => {
        console.log('A new FCM message arrived!', JSON.stringify(remoteMessage));
        PushNotification.localNotification({
          title: remoteMessage.notification.title,
          message: remoteMessage.notification.body,
          vibrate: true,
          vibration: 300,
          playSound: true,
          soundName: 'default',
          actions: ["Yes", "No"],
          channelId:"fcm_fallback_notification_channel"
        })
      });
      return unsubscribe;
    }, []);
```

This is the code to show a notification. I am also getting the console.log()

Answer (score 0):

The push notifications might not work properly in the Android emulator and iOS simulators so you should have to test the notification on the physical device only.

If you are using the FCM messaging then you can see this in their documentation about notifications can be sent to real device.

Comment: Ugh that sucks. Thank you. We are getting it to show on the device successfully. Just not on the emulator.